# How to make ".php" extension optional in IIS Windows 10

Tags: php, iis, windows-10, fastcgi

I have installed PHP on my local windows machine and have got PHP sites working through IIS using a FastCGI handler.

However, I am facing an issue with a site that tries to reference php files without their extension (.php).

**Example:**
http://dev.lvv.com/properties.php (works)
Does not work: http://dev.lvv.com/properties (404)

The Fast CGI PHP handler maps to urls that match "*.php" so I am at a loss as to how to sort this out.

Thanks